# Android: How to View PDF asset via Google Drive?

Tags: android, pdf, android-contentprovider, google-drive-android-api

So in an Android app, I've got a ContentProvider providing assets from my app -- and it's working just fine with ACTION_SEND to send PDFs to Google Drive.

And elsewhere I'm viewing PDF URIs with Google Drive via various ACTION_VIEW Intent -- including "content" URIs from a FileProvider.

But when I try to use Google Drive to view the same PDF asset URIs I can successfully "send", Google Driven gives an error about "invalid format", though everything looks just fine in the debugger.  (And, yes, I'm adding Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION.)

Is there a known issue with Google Drive in this regard?  Or is there something special to using ACTION_VIEW with assets via a ContentProvider -- as compared to other content URIs or to ACTION_SEND?